# How do I input data from Python FLASK to a database?

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, database, flask

I've got the below Python code:

```
@restServer.route("/sendData", methods=['POST'])
def client():
ID = request.form.get('ID')
name = request.form.get('name')
postcode = request.form.get('postcode')
dateofbirth = request.form.get('dateofbirth')
balance = request.form.get('balance')
description = request.form.get('description')

insert_stmt = (
    "INSERT INTO clients (ID, name, postcode, dateofbirth, balance, description) "
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

)
data = (ID, name, postcode, dateofbirth, balance, description)
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
conn.commit()
print("Did we do it?")
return jsonify(data)
```

I've also got the below HTML code:

```
  <form method="POST">
         <p>ID of your Avenger:</p> <input type="number" id="ID" required> 
       <p>Name of your Avenger:</p> <input type="text" id="name" required> 
         <p>Post Code of your Avenger:</p> <input type="text" id="postcode" required> 
          <p>Date of Birth of your Avenger:</p> <input type="date" id="dateofbirth" required> 
          <p>Bank balance of your Avenger:</p> <input type="number" id="balance" required> 
          <p>Description of your Avenger:</p> <input type="text" id="description" required> 


        <button class="button1" type="button" id="hashButton" onclick="nameInput()">Submit</button></form>
```

And finally the below Javascript code:

```
  function nameInput() {
   var words = document.getElementById("ID", "name", "postcode", "dateofbirth", "balance", "description" ).value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  document.getElementById("nameInputReturn").innerHTML = 
  json.name;
  }
  }

        xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/sendData", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
 urlencoded");
        xhttp.send(words);
    }
```

I'm trying to make it so you can input data into the form and then it will upload that data into the database. I've figured out how to input data that I specify in the code, by simply changing the parts variables inside the 
`data = (ID, name, postcode, dateofbirth, balance, description)` line. Currently, the submit button is clicked but the database just adds a line which has NULL for every column.

I'm quite new to Flask, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need to use JS to submit a form, even though using HTML would be the easier option?

Answer (score 2):

Your front end is kind of a mess. It seems like you are trying to send the `POST` request through JS, when your HTML could do it better and easier.

Try removing the listener from your submit button and changing your opening form tag to something like `<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/updateName">`.

You should also change all of your `id` attributes to `name`. This is because the `id` attribute does not get sent to the server. The name attribute, however, is sent and used to access the form's information from the server.

This should be a good place to start:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/updateName">
  <p>ID of your Avenger:</p> <input type="number" name="ID" required> 
  <p>Name of your Avenger:</p> <input type="text" name="name" required> 
  <p>Post Code of your Avenger:</p> <input type="text" name="postcode" required> 
  <p>Date of Birth of your Avenger:</p> <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" required> 
  <p>Bank balance of your Avenger:</p> <input type="number" name="balance" required> 
  <p>Description of your Avenger:</p> <input type="text" name="description" required> 
  <button class="button1" type="button" id="hashButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```